# How do I check for nulls when called an event from another script?

Tags: unity

```
 public GameObject OnComplete;
void Start()
{
    FindObjectOfType<ThirdBossSpawn>().CompletionLevelOne += OnCompletionScreen;
}



void OnCompletionScreen()
{
    OnComplete.SetActive(true);
}

public void AccomplishScreen()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

I got nullreference error on this error `" FindObjectOfType<ThirdBossSpawn>().CompletionLevelOne += OnCompletionScreen;"`  But I'm not sure how to check for nulls in terms on this situation considering "ThirdBossSpawn" is from another script

Comment: assigning the result of `FindObjectOfType<ThirdBossSpawn>()` to a variable and checking this against null before setting the listener is not working for you?

Comment: Are you sure the script is attached to a GameObject in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class where you store all the boss references.
Let's call it *BossSpawnManager*
Then cache it in your script and use it

```
public BossSpawnManager bossSpawnManagerRef;

void Start()
{
      if (bossSpawnManagerRef != null)
      {
            bossSpawnManagerRef.CompletionLevelOne += OnCompletionScreen;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you check for nulls for *literally* anything else.

```
void Start()
{
    var thirdBoss = FindObjectOfType<ThirdBossSpawn>()

    if (thirdBoss != null) thirdBoss.CompletionLevelOne += OnCompletionScreen;
}
```

But honestly, if you're getting a null here, it means you have set up your scene incorrectly. You have a script that depends on a `ThirdBossSpawn` script when no such script instance can be found. So just suppressing the null error won't fix this more fundamental problem.